# How to get the date value from html textarea via JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this function that creates a number of `textareas` depending on what month it is.

For example:

- If it's 'February', then 28 'textareas' are created.
- If it's 'March', then 31 'textareas' are created and so on.

When the user clicks on the 'textareas' and then the forms button, the value of the textareas inserts into the MySQL database.

My problem right now is that the value that goes into the database is not the value of the textareas, e.g. `2018-02-19`, it is always `2018-02-28`.

Functions:

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    var days;
    switch (month) {
        case 1: // Feb, our problem child
            var leapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
            days = leapYear ? 29 : 28;
            break;
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 8:
        case 10:
            days = 30;
            break;
        default:
            days = 31;
    }
    return days;
}

var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var weeks = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuseday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(), forDate.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
            var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
            textarea.setAttribute("type", "button");
            textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("value", newdate + "-" + day1);
            textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1);
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("day", newdate + "-" + day1)
            textarea.innerHTML = newdate + "-" + day1;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable(showDate);
};
```

html:

```
<form class="" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <table id="table">
        <input id="day"type="hidden" name="day" value="">
        <input id="btn"  type="submit" name="" value="Press">
</form>
```

php

```
$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_request['day']);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($day); $i++) {
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO calendar (day) VALUES('$day[$i])')";
    if (empty($day)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Error";

        header('Location: insert.php', true, 303);
        exit();
    } else {
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
            header('Location: insert.php', true, 303);
            exit;
        } else {
            $error= "Error: " .mysqli_error($conn);
            echo "$error";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick warning; You should only one `textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");` if you use multiple it will always use the second.

Comment: @scagood thanks! Must have missed that!

Comment: You may also want to generate `<td> ... </td>` tags for each row, I believe most browsers will fix/interpret `<tr> ... </tr>` on it's own correctly, however, it's probably good practice.

Comment: For you html/JS, are you trying to get a single row with all the days in cells, or one row per day?

For your PHP/SQL, are you trying to add one day per row, or multiple?

Comment: I am trying to take one value from the textarea, and then insert that one value into the database. Not sure if that made anything clearer

Comment: @Alison, then you should use `<input type="radio" name="day" value=... />` instead and you should not handle "arrays" in PHP OR javascript to set the value of hidden input the value of the click target

Comment: Your JS code is currently generating something like this: https://gist.github.com/scagood/a2c17b2113af0c2043617beb69d43bd3 right?

Comment: @4esn0k thanks! I did that before, but then im not able add text on top of the radio button. I need to use something like a textarea

Comment: @scagood exactly, but the type is not a button.

Comment: @Alison, <label for="day-1"> label should be here </label><input id="day-1" type="radio" name="day" value=... />

Comment: @4esn0k unfortunately, that did not work when I tried it

Comment: I'm struggling to see where the 'buttons' part comes to play. Also, shall we migrate this to a conversation?

Comment: @scagood Im not using buttons. Yes, we should move this to a conversation!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the data sent to `insert.php` looks like this(check using network tab)

```
day=2018-02-01&day=2018-02-02&day=2018-02-03&day=2018-02-04&day=2018-02-05&day=2018-02-06&day=2018-02-07&day=2018-02-08&day=2018-02-09&day=2018-02-10&day=2018-02-11&day=2018-02-12&day=2018-02-13&day=2018-02-14&day=2018-02-15&day=2018-02-16&day=2018-02-17&day=2018-02-18&day=2018-02-19&day=2018-02-20&day=2018-02-21&day=2018-02-22&day=2018-02-23&day=2018-02-24&day=2018-02-25&day=2018-02-26&day=2018-02-27&day=2018-02-28
```

It seems it is taking the last value because of same key name.

Instead of directly submitting the form,submit it using ajax and send the data in an array or as an object

Comment: So I also noticed that, but I thought that it would take "&day=2018-02-04" as the value in the DB. But how would I do it via ajax and then send it as an array??

Comment: That, or change `textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");` to `textarea.setAttribute("name", "day" + day1);`

Comment: @JDB thanks! I tried that bu now it wont insert anything to that db at all

Answer (score 1):

In this case your date fields should be named as an array. If you name multiple fields as `day`, it will act as single field take the last field value with the same name. So you have to change in one line and it will work nicely.

```
 textarea.setAttribute("name", "day[]");
```

Comment: Thanks Jaber! I tried that, but now it wont insert anything at all.

Comment: This is a nice a succinct answer, however, you may need to offer a little more as an explanation. and how to deal with the $_POST data.

Comment: i forgot the php code to handle posted array field. To check value is posting or not use `fiddler`.

Comment: @scagood do I need to change my php code? Not sure that I quite understand what you guys mean

Comment: Hope this will help you to know, how to handle posted array data..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090055/handling-array-field-post-data

Comment: Can you provided a small snippet of your PHP code, so we can see if it's something there?

Comment: @scagood I added the edited version of my php code. Tried following the link above

Comment: @Alison, I think first you have to know how to deal with posted data in PHP. Your PHP code is not near the correct one.

Comment: @JaberKibria I wrote that I tried to follow it. I did not say that it was perfect.. If I knew how to write perfect code I would not ask a question.. :(

Comment: I gave you a link in previous comments. Please follow it. I'm not php developer. So that I'm unable to provide you the actual code.

Comment: @Alison, @JaberKibria, can the hidden input - ` <input id="day"type="hidden" name="day" value="">` - cause any problems? As it's better to change it's name to `day[]` may be... or remote it...

Comment: @JaberKibria I wrote that I did follow the link and that it did not work. I believe that if you do not know php, then you should maybe say if someones code "is not near the correct one".

Comment: why are you shouting? Even you don't  know, in which side the problem is? First learn what is html inputs, and how it deals with server side.

Comment: @JaberKibria Im not shouting. I just thought that you were a bit rude.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript

Right, lets first start with the JavaScript.

```
function drawTable(forDate) {
    // Days in a month
    const daysInMonth = new Date(
        forDate.getFullYear(),
        forDate.getMonth() + 1,
        0
    ).getDate();
    // 28

    // Start of a date
    const date = [
        forDate.getFullYear(),
        (forDate.getMonth() + 1 + '').padStart(2, 0)
    ]
    .join('-');
    // 2018-02

    // Reset the table
    const table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";

    // For each day of the month
    // Start at one, go until day > daysInMonth. e.g. (1 -> 28)
    for (let day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
        const dateString = date + '-' + (day + '').padStart(2, 0);

        // Create the elements.
        const row = document.createElement("tr");
        const cell = document.createElement("td");
        const textarea = document.createElement("textarea");

        textarea.setAttribute("name", "day[]");
        textarea.setAttribute("value", dateString);
        textarea.innerHTML = dateString;
        textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day);

        // These do nothing.
        // textarea.setAttribute("type", "button");
        // textarea.setAttribute("day", dateString)

        // Stack the children into the table.
        cell.appendChild(textarea);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        table.appendChild(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

---

### PHP

Now, lets move on to the PHP.
I'm going to first look at the problems in your code.

```
// Currently 'day' is an array.
// So this will throw an error.
$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_request['day']);

// For every '$day[$i]' in '$day'
for ($i = 1; $i < count($day); $i++) {
    // $day is still an array.
    if (empty($day)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Error";

        // The problem that you'll face here is that
        // one empty day fails the rest of the days
        header('Location: insert.php', true, 303);
        exit();
    } else {
        if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO calendar (day) VALUES('$day[$i])')")) {
            // Here this will stop on the first '$day[$i]'
            header('Location: insert.php', true, 303);
            exit;
        } else {
            $error= "Error: " .mysqli_error($conn);
            echo "$error";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm going to look at a possible solution.

```
// Currently 'day' is an array.
$days = $_request['day'];

// This is how we can carry our errors.
$error = array();

// For every 'day' in the 'days' array.
if (is_array($days))
foreach ($days as $day) {
    // Escape the day.
    $day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $day);

    // Now this will work as expected.
    if (empty($day)) {
        // We shall use the $error array.
        $error[] = array(
            'day' => $day,
            'error' => 'day was empty'
        );
    }

    // Else if there is an error in the SQL query.
    else if (
        !mysqli_query(
            $conn,
            // You see how the '$day' variable is used
            "INSERT INTO calendar (day) VALUES('$day)')"
        )
    ) {
        // We shall use the $error array again here.
        $error[] = array(
            'day' => $day,
            'error' => mysqli_error($conn)
        );
    }
}

// If there was an error.
if (count($error)) {
    // Print the errors.
    print_r($error);
}

// Do your redirect.
header('Location: insert.php', true, 303);
```

---

### HTML

Finally, let's look at the HTML.
I'm going to first look at the problems in your code.

```
<!-- You do not need to define the blank 'class' -->
<form class="" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <!-- You should close the <table> tag. -->
    <table id="table">

    <!-- This is currently unneeded and could hinder the php. -->
    <input id="day"type="hidden" name="day" value="">

    <!-- You do not need to define the blank 'name' -->
    <input id="btn" type="submit" name="" value="Press">
</form>
```

Now, I'm going to look at a possible solution.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <table id="table"></table>
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Press" />
</form>
```

---

*Note: * I have not tried this code.

Comment: tried this, but im not able to insert anything to the db now

Comment: Try removing the `header('Location: insert.php', true, 303);` and see if there are errors.

Comment: Hi! Tried removing it, and got the following error msg: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 10. It refers to the foreach loop

Comment: I added this if stmt before the foreach stmt, and then the error disappeared, but nothing inserts into the db: if(is_array($day)){ }

Comment: Oh, sorry, that one is on me. `textarea.setAttribute("name", "day")` should be `textarea.setAttribute("name", "day[]")` this is because we need to make 'day' an array in the $_request array. (What the other answers say)

Comment: Also, you're right `if (is_array($days)) {` probably should be placed before the foreach.

Comment: So I added the "textarea.setAttribute("name", "day[]");" but still nothing in the db